# How to debug post and get php script in server

Tags: php, mysql, swift

Hi I am currently working on an iphone project and the mysql DB was hosted in AWS.

The previous developer had wrote many php scripts hosted in AWS that do post and get to the mysql server in AWS.

I would need to write a few similar php scripts (update, delete insert etc) that do post and get and I wonder where can I check the PHP println or echo messages?

Obviously I can't check them in xcode and if not, where in the server I could see those messages?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could just call the url (with proper parameters) from a browser. That way you will see (view source) the output from the php scripts.

Comment: Can this url and the proper parameters be checked from the xcode?  I don't see them in xcode log messages.

Comment: To see what is being sent (xcode?) to the server, you could create a quick little script that logs the parameters seen in the request. You could append to a log file, or similar.

Comment: If you're asking how to debug the code on the iphone, that would be a different question to ask with specific tags for that audience.

Comment: For API calls I use a REST client, like Postman etc.

Comment: So, that would make seeing the url to use to test your PHP script easy.

Comment: Tested postman a while ago, managed to get the echo output in postman too.